# Editor invited after accept minor revisions required

Tags: editors

I sent an article and it was accepted minor revision required. After resubmitting the paper the status appeared editor invited and has not changed in more than a week. The first time I submitted it, they just assigned an editor. What does this mean?

Comment: It means you should chill out.

Answer (score 1):

To wait and not to worry.
Editor might be busy to handle your submission. 
You might expect that since it is a minor revision, then it will be accepted almost immediately. Sometimes it is indeed the case. But this depends how efficient the journal is.

Comment: But this depends on...?